# Meaning of 'resolution' in regression

Tags: regression

I'm reading a paper and wonder what 'resolution' mean in this context.

> To speed the regression process, we use scale factors to quantize each
> of these variables as integers. The resolution of variable 1 (Time)
> is one second. The resolution of the dimensionless variable 2 is 0.1. The resolution of variable 3 (Altitude) is 200 ft.

Does resolution mean 'unit' in this context?

Comment: I read this as the smallest possible difference between values reported.  so that you are measuring to the nearest mm, km, g or whatever.  So times for 100 m sprint or dash were reported to a resolution of 0.1 s when I was young and now are reported to a resolution of 0.01 s.

Comment: "Quantize" evidently means to *bin* the data.  The "resolution" is the common width of the bins.  Without more context, it is unclear how this procedure would "speed the regression process," if at all.  Typically it does not improve the statistical features of the regression, because it loses some information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you can tell when objects are separated by $200$ feet of altitude. If they are separated by $201$ feet, they appear to have different altitudes. If they are separated by $199$ feet, they do not.

This terminology is common in sciences that use microscopes (telescopes, too). A microscope that can distinguish features that are a nanometer apart lets you see more detail than your naked eye that can distinguish features that are millimeters or perhaps centimeters apart. You might get a better sense of how this works by reading about microscopes, since it turns out that there’s really nothing statistical about this issue.